# Can't push to GitHub? (error: git-lfs died of signal 11)

Tags: git, github

After I've updated my Mac to ver. 10.13.3 (17D47) I can't push to GitHub.

I get the following messages:

```
error: git-lfs died of signal 11
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git'
```

I've trying deleting my SSH key on GitHub create new on the Mac and reconnecting it again with no effort.

Also, created .ssh/config file with the following:

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and still get the same two errors when trying to push.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: see this issue https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2439

Comment: It's not that, is somehow related with Mac update and SSH

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so this was solved, finally and GitHub looks green again after many days of local work :)

The problem was git-lfs (Git Large File Storage) and because it was blocking large files for uploading the second error was also shown.

1) I've uninstalled git-lfs from my system with the following commands because apparently there is not yet an uninstaller.

```
$ git config --global --unset filter.lfs.required
$ git config --global --unset filter.lfs.smudge  
$ git config --global --unset filter.lfs.clean 

# confirm all git lfs settings are gone
$ git config -l | grep lfs
```

1.1) This did not remove it completely, by using the command:

```
which git-lfs
```

Locate the folder where it is, then use the Finder > Go > GoToFolder... and enter the path to find it, then just move it to trash from there.

2) After that, simply re-install it with  Homebrew, run:

```
brew install git-lfs
```

2.1) I installed git-lfs previously before the uninstall hoping that will auto-reinstall it, but that did not happen and after running the command, Homebrew says git-lfs is installed but is not linked and by running:

```
brew link git-lfs
```

git-lfs is linked and **the problem is solved**.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.